# Java library or strategy to tell if an image contains a signature

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image file, and I need to determine if a specified area of this image contains a signature.  Or to put it in end-user terms, "Has this document been signed?"

What I have done so far is to examine all the pixels contained in the area, to calculate an average "darkness", and compare that to a reference value.  If the difference in darkness exceeds some threshold, then I consider it signed.

The problem with this (admittedly simplistic) approach is that because the pixels of the signature itself are such a small fraction of area, I have to use a very low darkness threshold, which results in a large number of false positives. I can't distinguish a real signature from stray markings, smudges, fax artifacts, etc.

To be clear...I'm not trying to match any **specific** signature or set of signatures.  That is, I don't care **who** signed it, only whether it is signed.

Is anyone aware of a Java library that can do this, or of a better approach to this problem than what I am currently doing?

**EDIT:**

This is an [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/al2ui2byt4ocbnz/sample_fax_template.pdf) of the kinds of images I am working with. This document would be faxed to the recipient, signed and faxed back.  It won't be this clean-looking by the time I need to look for a signature.

Comment: Instead of using the average darkness, maybe look to see if there are lines of pixels greater than some value.  So, for instance, find the first non-white pixel, then see how many non-white pixels are connected to it in any direction.  You could even check if there is more than one region, in the off chance they sign it in manuscript instead of cursive.  Or, if there is a single area with more than some number of pixels, in case they sign an "X".

Comment: Could you upload a few example images..? I have worked on a similar problem recently and I believe I can help you out.

Comment: @scap3y I've added a link to an example image.

Comment: Could you also upload an image with a signature?

Comment: BTW, the method I used was: detect regions with text using [this](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/objdetect/doc/erfilter.html) and then remove them. If there are any pixels which are left out, then the image goes into a slightly deeper test (this essentially removes all the "normal" text).

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any simple solutions. You can wrap over [queXF](http://quexf.sourceforge.net/)  or write something similar in Java. [This paper](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/6587611/A-Colour-Code-Algorithm-For-Signature-Recognition) talks about color code algorithm to recognize signatures.

Comment: The paper referenced deals with recognizing specific signatures: "Does this image match X's signature?"  My question is: "Does this image contain any signature whatsoever?"

Answer (score 1):

This is what I believe can be done (although not a very good solution) but may still work. It would involve a bit of machine learning. I am assuming that your image does not contain hand written text and its just an image.

First thing to do would be to create a dataset of images which contain a signature and those which do not. The positive samples of the dataset should only contain signatures (you can learn a classifier for multiple aspect ratios) and negative samples should contain random images of the same aspect ratio/dimension. Now, you can compute some feature over these samples (HoG can be used as a feature, although I do not claim it is the best one to use for this application) and learn a SVM for each aspect ratio.

The next step would be to slide a detection window (of different aspect ratios) throughout the image and use the multiple SVMs you have learnt and check if any of them gives a positive response.

Although this approach may not work always, but should give a decent amount of accuracy. The more data you will use to learn, the better the results would get (and if you can come up with a good feature vector to represent a signature, it would help you case even further)

Comment: The method suggested by Bharat can work quite well. I am employing the same sliding window approach but instead of an SVM I am using a Constitutional Neural Network which works considerably better. Also with the sliding window approach you can account for classifiers false positives by creating bit map intensities (Increase pixel value where you get a positive) and using a threshold on the max pixel intensity value.